# Resistor Values to switch a 100ma led with a on a 5v power supply with 2n3094a 3.5v base

Tags: led, transistors, infrared

I have a 100ma infrared led (1.2-1.4v), a 2n3904 transistor and an arduino-alike with a 3.5 and 5v power supplies, and 3.5v digital output.

I tested my stuff driving the LED directly (with appropriate resistor) and it was fine, but very short range, so I put in the transistor to beef up the power... But as a bit of noob to hardware have got stuck...

I used 2 100ohm resistors cos they are only .25w, and I worked out this would give the led 80ma and they'd split 0.32w.

What should the base resistor be (R3)? (and how should I have calculated it?) I tried an online simulator and put in a rheostat for some trial and error, expecting to do some reverse engineering when I got a figure) but I was getting readings of the base drawing 4amps... which didn't seem to make sense...

Help! Thanks.

[[image: The image has some spurious figures on it, I couldn't work out how to do it better[1]]

Comment: If you know what the base current Ib needs to be , and you know what the voltage on the base Vb will be Vb, then you ought to be able to calculate R3 = (3.3-Vbe) * Ib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple. For minimum power loss in the transistor, you want it to be in saturation. In this condition, the rule of thumb is that a gain of 10 to 20 is reasonable. So, for an LED current of 80 mA, you want a base current in the vicinity of 5 to 10 mA. Assume a 0.7 volt base emitter drop and you should be able to figure out the base resistor.

Comment: Ok, 3.5v-0.7v = 2.8v

Comment: Oops posted before finished...

Ok, 3.5v-0.7v = 2.8v .. 2.8/.01 = 280 and 2.8/.015 = 186, so a 220 is about in the middle, and 2.8*.015 = .042w means a .25 will be fine.

Is the 10/20 good for most such transistors? and is the .7 base/emitter drop a rule of thumb, or somewhere in the datasheet?

Comment: The 0.7 V base-emitter drop is a characteristic of a silicon diode which is what the base-emitter junction is. It will vary a little depending on current and temperature. You can measure it with your multimeter's diode test function. It applies a couple of volts but current limited to the test probes and displays the voltage between the probes. '1---' indicates over-range. Try it on an LED too. (My multimeter test voltage isn't high enough to exceed the \$ V_f \$, forward voltage, of even a red LED. See [I/V curves](http://lednique.com/current-voltage-relationships/iv-curves/) for more.